# Label Conversion from string to double isn't valid

Tags: vb.net

I have the following  code , It's for countdown timer

```
 Dim countdown As Integer = SharpTextBox6.Text
    Label1.Text = "Sending to " + "" + SharpTextBox4.Text + "" + "For" + countdown.ToString - 1
```

the problem is it says " Conversation from string "The value ..." to double isn't valid . Why does it covert into to double ? and how I can solve this problem

Comment: Do you can try this : Label1.Text = "Sending to " +  SharpTextBox4.Text + "For" + (countdown - 1).ToString

Comment: No problem,I copy so my comment in response

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
Label1.Text = "Sending to " + SharpTextBox4.Text + "For" + (countdown - 1).ToString
```

Answer (score 1):

**MSDN**: [***When you use the + operator, you may not be able to determine whether addition or string concatenation will occur. Use the & operator for concatenation to eliminate ambiguity and provide self-documenting code.***](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9c5t70w2%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

```
Label1.Text = "Sending to " & SharpTextBox4.Text & " For " & (countdown - 1)
```